# Como salvar formulário no android studio e enviar pro firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Tenho um formulário simples, com nome, sobrenome e idade. eu quero enviar os dados digitados no editText deste formulário para o firebase.  As soluções encontradas na web smp são referentes a formulários de login o que deixa o código muito complexo.

Já criei o arquivo json no firebase chamado pessoa e os nó "nome", "sobrenome"  e"idade" devem receber os valores do formular... se alguém puder me orientar em como fazer isso eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o seguinte: Pegar a referencia do firebase:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Depois criar os campos nos quais serão inseridos os dados:

```
    nomeEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_nome);
    sobrenomeEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_sobrenome);
    idadeEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_idade);
```

Pegar o que foi digitado nesses campos:

```
    final String nome = nomeEdit.getText().toString();
    final String sobrenome = sobrenomeEdit.getText().toString();
    final String idade = idadeEdit.getText().toString();
```

Então depois você pode usar um Map para inserir os dados digitados nos EditTexts.

```
private void SalvarDados(String userId, String nome, String sobrenome, String idade) {
        String key = mDatabase.child("usuario").push().getKey();

        Post post = new Post(userId, nome, sobrenome, idade);
        Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

        Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
        childUpdates.put("/usuario-dados/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

Para exibí-los, é só criar um adapter na atividade principal da sua aplicação.

Comment: cara não funcionou.

Comment: Envia todos os erros e o log também.